# What is "bw_and" in hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I found a strange query implemented in my project, when I debug and inspect the persistance.query Object just before it call getResultList() method, the queryString I found is :

`FROM AbcTbl a WHERE bw_and(a.column1, :column1) <> 0`

This query is working fine and fetching all data from AbcTbl table where a.column1= :column1.

I am not able to understand yet what is **bw_and** in this query syntax.
Could anyone have any idea?

I am using sqlServer2014 and direct query with bw_and is not acceptable by sqlServer.

Comment: It's a [Bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) syntax for **bitwise AND**.

Comment: Aah, right.
In my application sqlServerDilact is overriden and bw_and is registered as bitwise operator. That's why this is specific to my application. Thanks @chsdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My application below class is used which register *bw_and* as bitwise operator

```
public class ExtendedMSSQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public ExtendedMSSQLServerDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("bw_and", new BitwiseSQLFunction(BitwiseSQLOperator.AND, "bw_and"));
        registerFunction("bw_or", new BitwiseSQLFunction(BitwiseSQLOperator.OR, "bw_or"));
        registerFunction("cast_text_to_varchar_of_length", new CastTextToVarcharSQLFunction("cast_text_to_varchar_of_length"));
    }
}
```